# Issues deleting task using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Ill show the code snippet first and than try to understand where im getting the problem:
In task.js model file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'Data', 'tasks.json');

const getTasksFromFile = (cb) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, fileContent) => {
        if(!err){
            cb(JSON.parse(fileContent));
        }else{
            cb([]);
        }
    })
}


module.exports = class Task {
    constructor(description) {
        this.description = description;
        this.status = 'In Progress';
    }
    saveTask(){
        getTasksFromFile(tasks => {
            this.id = Math.random().toString();//Generate unique id for each task
            tasks.push(this);
            //add new task after checking for old ones.
            fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(tasks), (err) => {
                console.log('writing to file error: ', err);
            });
        })
    }
    
    static removeTaskById(taskId){
        getTasksFromFile(tasks => {
            const updatedTasks = tasks.filter(task => task.id !== taskId.toString());
            //save updated tasks to json fil
            fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(updatedTasks), (err) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log('Error updaing tasks list: ', err);
                }
                console.log(updatedTasks)
            })
        })
    }

    static fetchAllTasks(cb){
        getTasksFromFile(cb);
    }
}
```

adminController file :

```
    const Task = require("../models/task");
const {tasks} = require("../server/routes/admin");

exports.addNewTask = (req, res, next) => {
    const newTask = new Task(req.body.taskDesc);
    newTask.saveTask();

    res.redirect('/');
}

exports.removeTask = (req, res, next) => {
    const taskId = req.body.taskId;
    console.log('Task id: ', taskId);
    Task.removeTaskById(taskId);
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

what im trying to do is deleting a task using its id , the thing is im getting the correct id (checking using console.log('Task id: ', taskId) ) but when inside removeTaskById in task.js model folder it just doest work. but when i replace Task.removeTaskById(taskId) with  Task.removeTaskById(123) in adminController task is removed successfully.

I can guess that might have a connection to async function but after trying loging output to see where it might happend i couldn't manage to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're encountering might indeed be related to the asynchronous nature of file operations in Node.js. When you call Task.removeTaskById(taskId), it triggers an asynchronous file read and write operation inside the removeTaskById method. If your res.redirect('/') is executed immediately after calling Task.removeTaskById, it might happen before the file operations inside removeTaskById are completed.

First, modify your removeTaskById method in the Task class to return a promise that resolves when the file operations are complete:

```
static removeTaskById(taskId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getTasksFromFile(tasks => {
            const updatedTasks = tasks.filter(task => task.id !== taskId.toString());
            // Save updated tasks to json file
            fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(updatedTasks), (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error updating tasks list: ', err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(updatedTasks);
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Now, in your adminController file, you can use this promise to ensure that the redirection happens after the task is removed:

```
exports.removeTask = (req, res, next) => {
    const taskId = req.body.taskId;
    console.log('Task id: ', taskId);
    
    Task.removeTaskById(taskId)
        .then(() => {
            res.redirect('/');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // Handle the error here, if needed
            console.error(err);
            res.redirect('/');
        });
}
```

you can ensure that the redirection (res.redirect('/')) only occurs after the file operations inside removeTaskById are completed, either successfully or with an error.

Comment: Hi , thank you for helping, your solution worked for me (: will continue to learn about promises and async function ( do you have any tips how to how to recognize where there is might be async function ? and how to see it in advance and when to use it)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that the solution worked for you here are some topics where async await must used
Recognizing Asynchronous Operations:(API Requests, File Operations, Timers,Event Listeners,Promises and Async/Await)
Reading the Documentation
Understand Callbacks
Learn Promises
Async/Await
Error Handling